# SPA forms handling with Dataform Javascript - Not leaving form info in URL

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, single-page-application, dataform

I am working with express, mongoose and JavaScript to create a single page application. The code works , except **I dont want to keep form info in the URL with post request.** I tried redirect but it kind ended in loop - I think.

I am not using form method="post" because it will redirect the page and this is a SPA.
I would like not to show this or redirect from the URL to the same page without the query info.

> http://localhost:2000/*?firstName=John&lastName=James&age=40*

This is the form (index.html) --

```
<form id="formId">
      <input type="text" name="firstName">
      <input type="text" name="lastName">
      <input type="text" name="age">
      <button type="submit" onclick="processForm(event)">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is the  JS for the form handling :

```
function processForm(event){
  var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0])
  const queryString = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(formData.keys()).map(key => [
    key, formData.getAll(key).length > 1 ?
    formData.getAll(key) : formData.get(key)]));
  postData(queryString);   
}

async function postData(data) {
  fetch('/people', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response =>response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('Success:', data))
  .catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an SPA application and you want to handle the form via AJAX, you should stop the default form handler for the page (which is a redirection).

You can do that using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

So your code should look like this:

```
function processForm(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  ...rest of the form handling logic
}
```

Additionally you probably want to use the [form.onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event rather then button.onclick event to send the data.